# Is it possible to fetch only new links from Google Analytics API for last month?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My goal is to query Analytics, and if there is any new link created last month to some operations and store it in DB. And the problem is that i didn't find a way to query api just for new links in last month! I can compare it to DB query result, but i think it will slow down application, because result from db will have thousands of links, and api query also, comparing them will be inefficient resource usage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant request only new links from the Google Analytics API.  I don't see a filter helping here either because it will end up being to big.

My suggestion is you select everything out of Google Analytics store it in your DB.  Then at the end of the month you download all pages for that month into your DB. You will be able to search them there and find your new links.

Don't worry about inefficient resource usage.  I download millions of rows for customers every month in order to analyze there data further.  It's what the API is for.

Comment: I think @dalmto is spot on.  You pretty much have to use a brute force  approach.  I have actually created a service called "InboundLinkAlerts" (http://embeddedanalytics.com) which notifies a website owner when new links are detected.  Our approach is to query all historical ga:source and ga:referralpath and keep a data store.  Then about every 12 hours or so we query for all links over the last day, compare it to the store, etc.  One thing you have to be concerned about is sampledData. If you request to wide of a range the data could be sampled and some links left out.